# How to select a random value in a dictionary?

Tags: python, random, dictionary, key, jython

I created a `dictionary` where each `key` has more than one `value`.
The user will specify a key and the program must return one of the values ​​related to it registered in the dictionary.

For example:

```
Key = "The man"
Values ​​for this key = "get up" "sleep" "say hello".
```

When the user specify the key **"The man"**, the program needs to return **"sleep"** or **"get up"** or **"say hello"**.

How do I make a `random values`​​?

Comment: What language? Are you mapping a key to a value list?

Comment: How you make random values depends on your programming environment. Different platforms and frameworks provide random values through different mechanisms. If you specified what environment you're using, we may be able to help.

Comment: The language is Python. I'm using the JES 4.3 - Jython Environment for Students

Comment: In reality, the program first chooses a random key and stores it in a variable.
After the program should read the variable in which the key was stored and randomly choose one of the values ​​of this key.
And this procedure will occur multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`random.choice()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice)

```
>>> random.choice([1, 2, 3])
2
>>> random.choice([1, 2, 3])
1
>>> random.choice([1, 2, 3])
2
>>> random.choice([1, 2, 3])
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your programming language is python:

```
import random
di = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6], 'c':[7,8,9]}
random.choice(di['a'])
// returns a random value from the list
```

In your case,
    random.choice(yourDictionary['userEnteredValue'])
// Returns random value from the list associated with the key..